# Formula to find number of divisors of a number

Tags: prime-numbers, divisor-sum, primality-test

Consider the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{k}(\frac{1}{10^n-1}) = 0.122324243426 = a$. Where k is an arbitrary range we choose.

We can see that the decimal place of $10^{-n}$ is the number of divisors of n. This occurs because the sum basically acts like a sieve of eratosthenes, but within the decimal.

To find the value at $10^{-n}$ we can use :  $\lfloor\operatorname{mod}\left(a\cdot10^{x},10\right)\rfloor$

The issue with this is that it will work only if all the numbers less than $k$ have less than 10 divisors. To fix this we can just use a larger base and repeat the process, for example 100. 100 would work for $k < 10000$.

This seems like an obvious property and is even a direct formula as long as you have the exact value for $a$. Does this count as a closed form for the divisor function $\sigma_0(n)$ for $n<k$?

Comment: This could actually be more suited to https://CS.StackExchange.com, the Computer Science StackExchange website.  You can use this idea for a formula, but you'd have to use something like the Sieve of Atkin and Bernstein to calculate out the primes, or have some other way to find the divisors.  On the other hand, the divisor function $\tau(x)$ is a mathematical function (from number theory) that gives you the number of divisors of $x$, but you still need a way to calculate this function, which is again computer science.

Comment: I don't think the divisor function has a closed form. But yeah for computation questions it's better on stack exchange.

Comment: On the other hand, it's number theoretic, so you could compute it for primes and then apply the function based on factors.  I guess I'm not sure what you're asking...  In general mathematics I'd think that you'll always have the problem of needing many digits to describe the divisor function for large $n$.  You also have "Computational Science" Stack Exchange...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are describing is the [Lambert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series) generating function of the number of divisors of $n$ as given in the first example in the Wikipedia article. This is the
[OEIS sequence A000005](https://oeis.org/A000005) which also gives its generating function as
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_0(n) x^n = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k/(1 - x^k)
 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/(y^k - 1) \text{ where } y := 1/x.$$
As you noticed, if $y$ is a power of ten, then in the decimal expansion of the infinite sum the sequence appears up to the point where the sequence terms are bigger than $y$. The question of if this is a closed form for $\sigma_0$ depends entirely on the precise definition of "closed form" but there are several possible definitions of the term.

By  the way, the same idea work for other integer sequences and their generating functions. A famous example is the [Fibonacci numbers sequence A000045](https://A000045)
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty F_n x^n = x/(1 - x - x^2)
 = y/(y^2 - y - 1) \text{ where } y := 1/x.$$
If $y=10$ then we have $10/(10^2-10-1) = 10/89 \approx 0.1123595505$ where the first few terms of $F_n$ appear in the decimal expansion.